# Repository: does not exist gitlab

Tags: repository, debian, gitlab

From my admin area of `GITLAB`, when clicking to a project information, I have this error:
  `repository: does not exist.`

How to fix this error?

Someone have an Idea?

Thanks

Andry

Comment: What GitLab version are you using? on which OS? Is it a memory issue as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5228?

Comment: My version is: GitLab 6.9.2. 
I've doing this but the same error: repository: does not exist

Comment: Is there any project in your GitLab server for which it works?

Comment: yes, and there are also projects that work very well